# What can I do to unbrick my MacBook Pro after a software update?

Tags: macos, software-update

I applied the software update from 2015-03-10 on my 2009 MacBook Pro running Yosemite. Upon reboot, I get a grey screen with a circle and a slash through it. So far, I have tried:

1. Rebooting
2. Rebooting while holding down Command-Alt-P-R
3. Rebooting while holding down Shift (safe mode)
4. Rebooting while holding down Command-S. Same thing happens with the addition of the message, "Still waiting for root device"

Is there anything else I can do before re-installing? If I do re-install, any suggested procedure? The last physical install disk I have is likely a few versions outdated.

Comment: you get a + for been calm (considering the situation) and writing a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several other options your can try. First try rebooting/powering up and after your hear the chime press and hold the option/alt key. This will take you to the UEFI boot loader where you will be presented with all the boot options OS X recognizes. If you can, select the hard drive that contains your OS X installation.

Should the boot loader not launch or launch and then present you with no options reboot and then try pressing and holding command + r after the chime. This will either boot off of your recovery partition or attempt to boot your system from internet recovery. If it's the latter it will take some time so be patient.

Once you are loaded into recovery mode launch disk utility from the tools dropdown. Select the first entry for your hard drive in the side bar and then click "Repair Disk".

[image]

This will attempt to repair any errors with your partition map. Reboot and then hopefully all will now be functioning correctly.

Comment: Holding the alt/option key showed me an option to use the recovery partition to re-install the OS once I had an internet connection. It's odd that googling beforehand didn't clue me in to holding down alt while booting.